# Step in the derivation of eigenvalue spacing of a 2 by 2 random matrix

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

In [this CMSP online lecture](https://youtu.be/Je4bU3g_QGk) the following derivation of the eigenvalue spacing of a 2 by 2 matrix is carried out. I have a question about the change in coordinates below (in red):

To calculate the spacing distribution of a $2\times 2$ random matrix we start off with a real symmetric matrix

$$X_{[2\times 2]}=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&x_3\\x_3&x_2
\end{bmatrix}$$

with $X_1, X_2 \sim N(0,1),$ and the off-diagonal elements as $X_3 \sim N(0,\frac{1}{2}).$

The pdf of the spacing, $S,$ between eigenvalues is

$S=\lambda_2 - \lambda_1.$

The characteristic equation is

$$\begin{align}
\lambda^2 -\left(\mathrm {Tr} X \right)\lambda +\det X &= 0\\[2ex]
\lambda^2 -(x_1 + x_2)\lambda + x_1x_2 - x_3^2 &=0\\[2ex]
\lambda_{1,2} &= \frac{1}{2}\Bigg[x_1 + x_2 \pm \sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2-4(x_1x_2 - x_3^2)}\Bigg]\\[2ex]
S&=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 +4 x_3^2}
\end{align}$$

Now,

$$f_S(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx_1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{dx_2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{dx_3}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2)-x_3^2\right\}\delta\left(s-\sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + 4 x_3^2} \right)$$

At this point there is the following change of coordinates:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
\color{red}{x_1 - x_2 = r \cos \theta}\\
\color{red}{2x_3 = r\sin\theta}\\
x_1 + x_2 =\psi
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

> The question is: Are we just making these $X_1, X_2, X_3$ independent random variables dependent by using $r$ and $\theta$ for all of them? Is this change of variables legitimate, and why?

Comment: You're just doing an integral and change of variables is always a legitimate means to that end. Has nothing to do with the random variables.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I was almost certain that there wasn't a basic mistake in the derivation; however, I see that because of the change of variables we can say $(x_1 - x_2)/\cos\theta = 2x_3/\sin \theta,$ for example. Now, this is not a true statement...

Comment: I don’t see your point. Why is this not a true statement?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Let me make clear that this is no rhetorical question, or misguided attempt at finding a mistake. I just don't see why we can link this way three variables that are independent of each other, and not even distributed equally.

Comment: We are not linking the random variables. We are changing variables in an integral. This is a multi variable u substitution, that’s it.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen OK. Shouldn't there be, in this case, some sort of intrinsic geometrical relationship between these variables to allow such trigonometric substitution?

Comment: The variables are just coordinates, so no. The new coordinates just must cover the same space as the old and avoid some other pathologies

Comment: For instance, it looks like this transformation first rotates and stretches the grid lines  and then uses cylindrical coordinates